# Is there any difference between plt.legend and ax.legend in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

They seem to both work, and both are used in examples in https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html, though `plt.legend` is more common there. When should each be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.legend()` will implicitly invoke the `legend` method of `ax`. Using the `pyplot` interface, you sometimes do not know explicitly which axes you are dealing with. So the Matplotlib official documentation also [recommends using the `ax` method](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_summary.html#the-object-oriented-api)(object-oriented API). It gives you more control and customization.