# How to remove duplicates and move the legend list to outside of the graph concurrently?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, legend

I have seen many good questions questions and answers, but I am not sure how to combine two of them:

- [How to put the legend outside the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-outside-the-plot)
- [Duplicate items in legend in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385639/duplicate-items-in-legend-in-matplotlib)

These two questions have great answers, but I am unable to do both at the same time! Putting both code into a single function doesn't work:

```
def func():

  ...

  # revome duplicate legends
  legend(ax)

  plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

# remove duplicate legends
def legend(ax):
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    unique = [(h, l) for i, (h, l) in enumerate(zip(handles, labels)) if l not in labels[:i]]
    ax.legend(*zip(*unique))
```

I tried putting the code `plt.legend(...)` before and after `legend(ax)`:

- Putting the remove duplicate function before moving it outside of the plot area results in the legend being moved outside of the plot area, but **does not** remove any duplicate legends:
  [image]
- Removing the duplicate legends before moving the legends outside of the plot area for some reason also does not move the legend out of the plot area, but it removes the duplicate legends!
  [image]

How do I fix this to not only move the legend out of the plot area, **and** remove any duplicate legends?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any difference between plt.legend and ax.legend in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020745/is-there-any-difference-between-plt-legend-and-ax-legend-in-matplotlib)

Comment: No @MisterMiyagi, it doesn't really provide any information on how to solve my problem I think. If i misread or misunderstood anything, please let me know!

Comment: Both `plt.legend` and `ax.legend` are effectively the same, so each is going to override whatever you did with the previous call. You must combine the calls into one, not repeat them one after the other.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Oh whoops! Fixed, but the problem still occurs unfortunately (I changed everything to `ax.legend`), and how do I combine those two?

Comment: The point is that you must make only *one* call to `XYZ.legend`, no matter what `XYZ` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Credits to @MisterMiyagi for helping me out*

I had two errors in my code:

1. I used both `plt.legend` and `ax.legend`, so they overlapped each other
2. However that still doesn't fix the problem, I also had to make sure when running `ax.legend`, it had to be in **one command**, not multiple as they would *override* each other!

This will work:

```
def func():

  ...

  # revome duplicate legends
  legend(ax)

# remove duplicate legends
def legend(ax):
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    unique = [(h, l) for i, (h, l) in enumerate(zip(handles, labels)) if l not in labels[:i]]
    ax.legend(*zip(*unique), loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```